Selecting Two Entries From a Related Table
I have two tables; "Flight" and "Person".
Person has three columns; "id", "last", "first".
Flight has three columns; "id", "P1_id", "P2_id"
where P1_id is the row id of a "Person"
and P2_id is also the row id of a "Person".
I need to select every row from "Flight" with the appropriate "last" and "first" from "Person". Table data looks something like -
Person (id, last, first)

smith, john
jones, fred
glass, michael

Flight (id, p1_id, p2_id)

1, 2
2, 3
3,
3, 2

I need the output to look like -

smith, jones
jones, glass
glass
glass, jones

Thanks for your help.

You need to add the person table twice because your flight table has to persons, if you have more use the same number of JOIN
Use
    SELECT
    f.id, p.last, p1.last
    FROM Flight  f
    LEFT JOIN Person p ON f.p1 = p.id
    LEFT JOIN Person  p1 ON f.p1 = p1.id

